# How can a vector field in $E^3$ be represented by a linear combination of only 2 basis vectors?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, linear-algebra, covariance

In Chapter I.7 of "Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell", Zee introduces the concept of covariant derivatives. I am confused by the first line in this section (see below) as it appears that we can represent any vector field in a 3 dimensional euclidean space by $\overrightarrow{W}(x) = W^\mu(x)\overrightarrow{e_\mu}(x)$ where $\mu = 1,2$ and $\overrightarrow{e_\mu}(x)$  are the basis vectors for the tangent plane at point $x$ on some surface $\overrightarrow{X}$.

[image]

Now I can understand if we are first constraining ourselves to "observe the effects" of $\overrightarrow{W}(x)$ solely  on the surface $\overrightarrow{X}$, we may represent it a form that does not have a component outside the tangent plane, but then why would Zee even mention "In other words, it does not stick out of the surface"?

If we do  not have that constraint how does it make sense that we can describe a general 3 dimensional vector field with only two basis vectors?

Thanks for any perspective! (and apologies if I missed something very basic here.. I'm a bit out of practice)

Comment: Vectors in differential geometry are written in terms of a frame field which is defined locally, so two basis vectors is enough to describe vectors that live in the tangent space. Which claim the author makes, i.e. that the vector lies in the tangent plane.

Comment: Zee appears to be talking about a vector field on a 2D surface. Why do you think the same number of basis vectors would apply in 3D?